# The generator works strange

Tags: python, generator

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = (c for c in a if c in a)
a = [2, 3, 4]
print(list(b))


def d(expr):
    for c in expr:
        if c in expr:
            yield c


a1 = [1,2,3]
t = d(a1)
a1 = [2,3,4]
print(list(t))
```

output:

```
[2, 3]
```

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

question:
1) in the first variant, the cycle retains the old value of the list ([1,2,3]), but the conditional expression takes a new list a([2,3,4]).
2) how my own generator give me other result than generative expression?

For example, I replaced a on the real lists of the first example, I hope this will be more clear my first question.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = (c for c in [1,2,3] if c in [2, 3, 4])
a = [2, 3, 4]
print(list(b))
```

Output:

```
[2,3]
```

Comment: All references to `a1` within the function refer to the local variable `a1`. Changing `a1` in the global scope isn't going to affect that at all.

Comment: @glibdud realy? t1 = [1,2,3,4]
def r(t1):
    t1[0] = 10
r(t1)
print(t1) - i see, list change

Comment: That's not the same thing. Your comment's example is mutating an object within the function to mutate it globally. The example in your question simply rebinds `a1` in the global scope, which has no effect on the function's `a1` local variable.

Comment: A more appropriate comparison might be to change `a1 = [2,3,4]` to `a1[:] = [2,3,4]`, which will produce another (different) output.

Comment: Try instead with `a1[:] = [2, 3, 4]`.  That will give you `[2, 3, 4]`, because by the time execution reaches `for c in a1`, `a1` is `[2, 3, 4]`

Comment: I think your edit just makes it more confusing. Honestly, I'd remove all the code after the first four lines, because that's where the unexpected bit is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [PEP 289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#the-details), we can rewrite your generator expression as follows:

```
# b = (c for c in a if c in a)

def __gen(expr):
    for c in expr:
        if c in a:
            yield c
b = __gen(iter(a))
```

Here, a reference to `[1, 2, 3]` for use in the for loop is captured immediately (when you create `b`), but the `if c in a` check uses the new global `a` which is equal to `[2, 3, 4]`.

On the other hand, when you write a generator function, `a1` is passed to the function and stored for later use in both `for` and `if x in y` expressions. Assigning `a1 = [2, 3, 4]` has no effect.

To make the function do the same thing as the generator expression, all you need to do is replace `if c in expr` with `if c in a1`.

Comment: why "for c in expr:" but "if c in a:" in your code? i change own code on expression for greater visibility

Comment: @rtut If you're asking why Norrius did it that way, it's because that's how the linked PEP says it should be done. If you're asking why Python implemented it that way, [that's in the PEP, too](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#early-binding-versus-late-binding).

Comment: def d(expr):
    for c in expr:
        if c in expr:
            yield c


a1 = [1,2,3]
t = d(a1)
a1 = [2,3,4]
print(list(t))   this not new global variable? but code return the same? i asked why cycle save old list? and if take new list

Comment: @rtut If you change the last occurrence of `expr` in your code to `a1`, then it will be equivalent to what Norrius is showing you here and will give you the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @glibdud Edited the answer to include that.